Calling ABAP RAP actions( custom and standard both ) from UI5 Application
I have one RAP Application (Odata V2 + Managed) which I extended in VS Code.
Requirement:

Add Button for file upload which should display a dialog screen to upload the Excel file.
Read the data from the file.
Validate the records from the file and create/update existing records in the database table.

I have logic written for validating all the fields inside my behavior class in RAP.
Questions:

Is it possible to trigger the methods from the class in UI5?
How can I create the records from the content of the file (Basically how to trigger the create method)?
How to pass the data from the Excel file to the backend in RAP?

For file upload I found this SpreadSheet Importer, but I'm not sure how to pass the data from the Excel to backend and how to trigger the validation and create method.
